# Add custom DeserializerFactory to Jackson 2 ObjectFactory

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-modules

I'm attempting to upgrade from Jackson 1.x to 2.x.

One area I'm having problems is where I was using a custom DeserializerFactory it looked like this:

```
objectMapper.setDeserializerProvider(objectMapper.getDeserializerProvider()
                                                   .withFactory(myFactory));
```

setDeserializerProvider is now gone in Jackson2 (although setSerializerProvider is still there). I was looking at using SimpleModule but that doesn't have what I need either.

How is this supposed to work in 2?

**Update**:
I feel the need to emphasize that it needs to be a FACTORY. Not just registering a deserializer.

The custom factory passes information on to the Deserializer like this:

```
if (CollectionPage.class.equals(type.getRawClass())) {
        final JsonDeserializer<Object> contentDeserializer = type.getContentType().getValueHandler();
        return new MyCollectionDeserializer(type, contentDeserializer);
    }
```

That value (contentDeserializer) is different at runtime for collections containing different types.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work when you are using `SimpleModule` ?

Comment: SimpleModule lets you register JsonDeserializers, not factories. In my case it needs to be the Factory because the factory returns custom JsonDeserializers based on the CollectionType at runtime

Comment: It may be somewhat of a crossover of the other question but what I'm looking for was never answered. How to inject the factory.

Comment: I found the answer and posted it in the other question since it didn't actually have a proper answer to the question.